Should I create Dynamodb global secondary index for query with two keys
I am new to dynamodb and have new requirement. I have existing dynamodb table. In the table there are already thousand of records available with 3 global indexes.
Table structure



empId
departId
code




121
101
HRA


121
102
SWE


122
101
PPL



In this table there are empId, departId and code all are GSI as only partition key index. As this table has thousand of records.
Which is the correct way to query data base on empId and code key?
Do I need to create new GSI with empId as partition key and code as sort key?
Hi folks please let me know which is best solution for query data base on two keys i.e, empId and code and what will be keyConditionExpression?

Depending on which value you will always know, then you would create a GSI with that value as the partition key and the other as sort key.
Depending on your access patterns, you could combine both values into a single partition key, if you are always looking for a combination of both, but it would most likely be better as a partition/sort key combo.
KeyConditionExpression: "empId = 123 AND code = HRA"

How do I combine both value in single partition key? And can duplicate data insert?

No you cannot have duplicates. If you want to combine both partition and sort key into a single attribute you must do so on the client side.
